# Html change password validations failing

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xjdena) contains my HTML, CSS, and typescript code! and know why I can't able to see any validations!! I could able to submit a form, without any validations! any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.changePassForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     oldPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
     password: [null, Validators.compose([
       Validators.required,
       PasswordValidation.patternValidator(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/, {isPasswordValid: true})
     ])],
     confirm_password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
   }, {
     validator: this.checkPasswords 
   });

 }
checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
 let password = group.get('password').value;
 let confirmPassword = group.get('confirm_password').value;
 return password === confirmPassword ? null : { notSame: true }     
}
```

Hope this helps.